# What is the purpose of cross-validation?

Tags: statistics, classification, cross-validation, naivebayes

I am working myself through a book on machine learning right now.

Working on a `NaiveBayesClassifier` the author is very much in favour of the cross-validation method.

He proposes to split the data into ten buckets (files) and train on nine of them each time withholding a different bucket.

Up to now the only approach I am familiar with is to split the data into a training set  and a test set in the ratio of 50%/50% and simply train the classifier all at once.

Could someone explain what are possible advantages of using cross-validation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Machine Learning theory question, not software development.

Answer (score 5):

Cross-validation is a way to address the tradeoff between bias and variance.

When you obtain a model on a training set, your goal is to minimize variance.  You can do this by adding more terms, higher order polynomials, etc.

But your true objective is to predict outcomes for points that your model has *never* seen.  That's what holding out the test set simulates.

You'll create your model on a training set, then try it out on a test set.  You will find that there's a minimum combination of variance and bias that will give your best results.  The simplest model that minimizes both should be your choice.

I'd recommend "An Intro to Statistical Learning" or "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie and Tibshirani for more details.

Comment: So in simple terms: It is a method to minimize error when setting up a model that is to be used upon unseen data?

Answer (score 1):

The general objective of machine learning is that the more the data you have for training, the better results you would get. This was important to state before i start answering the question.

Cross-validation helps us to avoid overfitting of the model and it also helps to increase the generalization accuracy which is the accuracy of the model on unseen future point. Now when you divide your dataset into dtrain and dtest there is one problem with that which is if your function that would be determined once you have trained your model needs both training and testing data, then you cannot say your accuracy on future unseen point would be same as the accuracy you got on your test data. This above argument can be stated by taking the example of k-nn where nearest neighbour is determined with the help of training data while the value of k is determined by test data.

But if you use CV then k could be determined by CV data and your test data can be considered as the unseen data point.

Now suppose you divide your dataset into 3 parts Dtrain(60%), Dcv(20%) and Dtest(20%). Now you have only 60% of data to train with. Now suppose you want to use all the 80% of your data to train then you can do this with the help of m-fold cross validation. In m-fold CV you divide your data into two parts Dtrain and Dtest (lets say 80 and 20).
lets say the value of m is 4 so you divide the training data into 4 equal parts randomly (d1,d2,d3,d4). Now start training the model by taking d1,d2,d3 as dtrain and d4 as cv and calculate the accuracy, in the next go take d2,d3,d4 as dtrain and d1 as cv and likewise take all possiblity for m=1, then for m=2 continue the same procedure. With this you use your entire 80% of your dtrain and your dtest can be considered as future unseen dataset.

The advantages are better and more use of your dtrain data, reduce the overfit and helps to give you sured generalization accuracy.
but on the downside the time complexity is high.
In your case the value of m is 10.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have maximum no. of points to train the model to achieve accurate results.For every data point chosen in the train set, it is excluded from the test set. So we use the concept of k and k-1 where we firstly divide the data set into equal k sized bins and we take one bin make it a test set and the remaining k-1 bins represent train set. We repeat the process till all the bins are selected once as test set(k) and the remaining as training(k-1).Doing this no data point in missed out for training purpose